# ffmpeg image2 screen capture has noise lines

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to capture stills from my MTS file from my Sony HD camcorder.

This command:

```
ffmpeg -vframes 1 -i 00035.MTS -s 1440x1080  -f image2   output_single_frame2.jpg
```

produces this image http://i.minus.com/iYXQ4S7F1Mwq2.jpg which has a lot of lines. This doesn't happen when I try it on an flv file that I have.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that certain frames have those lines naturally. I collected 300 frames and the 300th one looked normal.

Comment: My guess is that the 300th frame is an I-frame, while the others are either P or B frames.  I-frames usually have much higher quality but only occur every few hundred frames by default in H.264 encoded videos.